# Strange behavior with as.character

Tags: r, posixct

I have a vector or POSIXct and when I do `as.character()` on it, it returns numbers instead of the characters. I unfortunately cannot reproduce this with toy data but this is what is happening:

```
d = as.POSIXct(c( "2015-09-08 17:42:07.456 GMT","2015-09-08 17:42:19.778 GMT"))
class(d) ##this returns POSIXct
```

but `as.character(d)` returns

```
"1441740168.0001", "1441740168.0001"
```

Why am I getting `"1441740168.0001", "1441740168.0001"` instead of dates in character format?

Comment: It works for me. `class(d)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"; as.character(d)
[1] "2015-09-08 17:42:07" "2015-09-08 17:42:19"`

Answer (score 0):

Internally it represents dates as seconds passed since origin moment in time. Consult [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) for details.

Comment: and if you want the printed representations, you are better off using `format`.